# how to analyze cloudwatch data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the best practice to analyze whether the `EC2 server/loadbalancer` is overloaded? We can  get some stats from `Cloudwatch` . But is there a user friendly way to analyze `Cloudwatch` data ??

---

**Question update**

What I have implemented is I have a `load balancer`, and an `autoscaling` group associated with it. In the autoscaling group , **min** no of instances is **2** and **maximum** is **10**. I have also set two `alarms` to for the **scaleUp** and **scaleDown** policy by **1**. The **scale down policy** is for `CPU Utilization` less than **20** , and **scaleUp policy** for `CPU Utilization` greater than **80**.

I have been trying analyze the data on `CloudWatch` . But I am yet not able to figure out the overload of my server. How much instances should be the **optimal minimal instances** running? How can i figure out these from the `cloud watch analytics`?

Comment: Can you please be more specific with your requirements?  What do you mean by "user friendly", and what "analysis" tasks do you want to perform?  There are many ways to assess whether your instance is overloaded or not; what criteria would you want to use?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. Thanks.